# Messagepack "partial" serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, msgpack

I have a class with some private and public fields and properties.

```
[MessagePackObject(false)]
public class Person
{
    [Key(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [IgnoreMember]
    private int _age;
    [Key(2)]
    public int Age { get { return _age; } set { _age = value; } }
}
```

In some cases I don't need to serialize `Age`, I need to serialize only some fields (for example only `Name`). So I need 2 methods, to serialize all object and partial serialize. How can I organize it?

Comment: If a person may or may not have an age, can you use a `int?`

Comment: I want to use default `int` value of person without age. After deserialization age can be 0.

Comment: You could serialize a private `int?` instead, and let the public default to whatever value you want, i.e. `_age ?? 0`

Comment: it does not matter. the problem is that I can't serialize only some selected fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to my own question.

The only solution I have found is to move `Name` to base class `BasePerson`. I will serialize object as `BasePerson` and then deserialize bytes to `Person`

```
[MessagePackObject(false)]
public class BasePerson
{
    [Key(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[MessagePackObject(false)]
public class Person
{
    [IgnoreMember]
    private int _age;
    [Key(2)]
    public int Age { get { return _age; } set { _age = value; } }
}
```

Usage:

```
Person person = new Person()
{
    Name = "Gor",
    Age = 26
};
var serializedBytes = MessagepackSerializer.Serialize<BasePerson>(person);
// will give me person with `Name` "Gor" and `Age` 0 (default value of int)
var personWithoutAge = MessagepackSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(serializedBytes );
```